# SSH allow windows AD groups(with Special charactors)

Tags: ssh, users, ldap

I have join my linux to windows domain succesfully, and now everyone in the domain is able to log in to the server by using ssh.

But we only want to allow certain users from a group to log in.

Example of current two groups:

```
#it_admin

Domain Admin
```

Comment: For a user from the group `Domain`, does the `groups` command list `Domain`?

Comment: So the `#` and the space are part of the group names? Neither of them are valid group names in Linux usually, so I cannot add one to test.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in two ways. One is to let the SSH configuration filter, and the other is to use `pam_access`.

### Using SSH configuration

To `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add a `AllowGroups` line:

```
AllowGroups Domain Admin
```

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

```
AllowGroups
    This keyword can be followed by a list of group name patterns,
    separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for
    users whose primary group or supplementary group list matches one
    of the patterns.
```

`Domain Admin` here doesn't match `Domain Admin` the group name, but two separate groups `Domain` and `Admin`. You'll have to use something like `Domain*Admin` and `*it_admin`, since neither  (space) nor (`#`) are usually valid characters in Linux groups. To be on the safer side, use `?` instead of `*`: `Domain?Admin` and `?it_admin`, so that only one character is allowed by the wildcard. You can also add a pattern-based DenyGroups section. See the `PATTERNS` section in [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html).

### Using `pam_access`

Add lines to `/etc/security/access.conf` of the form:

```
- : ALL EXCEPT (Domain) (Admin) : ALL
```

There are plenty of comments in that file which document how to use it. [`man pam_access`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_access.8.html) is quite bare, so most information would come from those comments. `pam_access` is more powerful in that it can control non-SSH logins as well (TTYs, GUI, etc.). This particular line, for example, should deny any user who does not have `Domain` or `Admin` as a group from logging in at all (unless other lines allow them).

Both approaches are pretty flexible, and I don't know the pros and cons, so no recommendations.

Comment: How about the group '#it_admin'? Please note there is a hash in front

Comment: You are amazing guy, it works in ssh config file. thks so much.  What does it mean of *? is it a match? How about if there is a group with name 'Domain Test Admin', can the users in this group login?

Comment: yes, it works. Just thinking of is there any way to convert these special characters?

Comment: Hi muru, I am using redhat acturely. But previously I have joint ubuntu to AD. https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/07/06/how-to-quickly-and-easily-add-a-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-system-to-microsoft-active-directory.     If can not convert special characters, how about escape? tried \ but not working.

Comment: Check if it is being converted. Try the `groups` command on an user who's in one of these groups.

Comment: Here are the results:                                                                       #groups testUser
testUser: testUser domain users domain admin #it_admin

Comment: So it is not being converted (except to lower case, but that's not much use). Going from the guide, you must be using winbind. Could you try with something else, like `sssd` (I don't know how to configure SSSD for AD, but it might convert special characters).