# alow Windows AD group to login via SSH

Tags: 14.04

I have edited sshd_config file by adding "AllowGroups

tried Combinations :

AllowGroups \GroupName
AllowGroups \GroupName

Comment: This works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545058/ssh-allow-windows-ad-groupswith-special-charactors

Answer (score 0):

**Active Directory Domain Membership**

First of all install the necessary packages.

```
apt-get install winbind libnss-winbind libpam-winbind
```

**Configure winbind /etc/samba/smb.conf**

Backup the original file and replace it with the following content.

```
[global] 
    workgroup = MYDOMAIN 
    netbios name = COMPUTERNAME 
    server string = %h with Samba %v
    realm = MYDOMAIN.DE
    allow trusted domains = no
    idmap config * : range = 50000-59999
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : default = yes
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : backend = rid
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : read_only = yes
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : range = 50000-59999
    winbind use default domain = yes 
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind offline logon = yes 
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    winbind cache time = 1
    template shell = /bin/bash 
    security = ADS 
    local master = no
    encrypt passwords = true
```

**Join the Active Directory Domain**

```
net ads join -U <Administrator>
```

**Configure Security**

Some manual work is necessary.
Make a backup of /etc/security/group.conf

Edit group.conf and create pam_winbind.conf with the following content.

pam_winbind.conf:

```
[global] 
        cached_login = yes 
        krb5_auth = yes 
        krb5_ccache_type = FILE
```

group.conf

```
* ; * ; * ; Al0000-2400 ; floppy, audio, cdrom, video, usb, plugdev, users
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat winbind 
group:          compat winbind
```

**Configure PAM**

/etc/pam-d/common-session

```
...     pam_unix.so 
session required    pam_mkhomedir.so    umask=0077
```

Comment: there is a typo in the path /etc/pam-d/common-session it should be /etc/pam.d/common-session